# How to create a "shared_ptr<StaticContainers>" with one allocation?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, tree, shared-ptr

Is there a way to create a `shared_ptr<pair<shared_ptr<void>, vector<uint32>>>` or an equivalent, with `make_shared()`, that only results in one heap allocation that contains the vector's data as well?

- It doesn't need to be a `vector<uint32>`!  The vector's size and data never changes after creation and it lives as long as the control block of this shared_ptr; vector isn't a good container for this I think, maybe there's another container or something that could help `make_shared()` combine the allocations together?
- The `void` refers to this same type `shared_ptr<pair<shared_ptr<void>, vector<uint32>>>` (it's recursive), and actually *shouldn't* contain it's control block as it'll be assigned from an existing shared_ptr of this type.
- If all else fails, I can figure out the overall size of the total allocation, `placement new` the objects into it, and write a custom destructor... but I um... don't know how to do that in 1 allocation, as that would require giving the `shared_ptr` a control block that I created myself, I... think?

*Background:*

I'm writing a tree that contains deltas for some data (draw state), where each leaf should control the lifetime of every path above it towards the root.

This is the first time I've used `shared_ptr` in a serious capacity, it seemed to fit the problem very well.  But I'm unsure how to make use of them efficiently...  This tree is constructed every frame and consumes a fair amount of time, so I'm trying different stuff to optimize it.

```
using std;  // only here to make this post readable

shared_ptr<pair<shared_ptr<void>, vector<uint32>>> node;
//                          /            /
//                         /            /
// This refers to the previous node,   /   
// 1 closer to the root of the tree;  /
// has the same signature as this    /
//                                  /
//                        this is the prev node's data at the time of the branch; 
//                        it is static and can never change 
//                        (what can I use besides a vector here to help with heap allocation?)  
//                        (must contain count info as well, maybe pair<size_t, unique_ptr<uint32>>?)
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me, but I think you might need something like `auto foo = std::make_shared<uint32[]>(size);` which is an array of size `size` and only performs 1 allocation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Thank you, that does sound ideal!  I suppose I just need to figure out how to combine that with `std::pair`, maybe something like `make_shared<pair<shared_ptr<void>, shared_ptr<uint32[]>(make_pair(prevPtr, size))`? (sorry for the mouthful)

Comment: AFAIK `shared_ptr` require an allocation for the internal counter (and deleter) so a pair of `shared_ptr` needs (at least) 2 allocations. Besides, why do you use `shared_ptr<void>` ? It seems unsafe to me as it should break the type system (so the deleter may not be called).

Comment: The [flatbuffers] is open souce project that constructs complex data structures in one buffer that are immutable after FlatBufferBuilder::finish call. May be you need that? Cascade of nested shared_ptr sure gets you nowhere.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - the `shared_ptr<void>` refers to a node 1 level down the tree, to an allocation that already happened.  It's void because the type is recursive (it's the type of the outer shared pointer), it remembers it's destructor, so it's safe to keep.

Comment: Ok for the destructor. Note that a shared pointer also store this and take care of atomically increasing the internal counter which may not be useful in your case (and adding overhead). For the `shared_ptr<void>` note that the shared pointer object has to [dynamically allocate a control block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) independently of your target object.